# Print out the abbreviations with printacronyms

Tags: acro

I have a problem with the `acro`-package and have not been able to find any answer or even anyone with the same problem. I am writing my thesis and since it is an area with a lot of abbreviations it is customary to have a list of abbreviations in the thesis. But when I use the `acro`-package everything except the writing of the list(e.g using `\ac{some abbreviation}` in the text). I have made a short test file just to make sure that it really is just the `\printacronyms`-command that does not work. The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{udp}{
    short = UDP,
    long = User Datagram Protocol
}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms
testing if it is possible to print out the abbrivitions, e.g \ac{udp}
\end{document}
```

I get Three errors, namely:

> ```
> !undefined Control sequence.\acro_sort_prop:NN...rop{##1}{##2}\seq_sort:Nn\I__acro_tmpa_seq{\int_co...
> !Undefined Control sequence.<argument>\LaTeX3error:A sequence was misused.
> !Undefined Control sequence.<argument>\sort_return_same:
> ```

I'm using TexMaker with pdfLaTeX. Tried to do it on a friends computer and it worked. Would rather see a solution where I don't need to use a different package or install some different software (e.g TexStudio..) since I've already produced quite a lot of text and I use the `\ac{}`-command a lot. 
I will be very grateful if somebody can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I could run your MWE without a problem. Maybe your packages are outdated. I have `acro.sty    2017/01/22 v2.7a` and `expl3-code.tex    2017/03/18 v7019`. Update your packages either via `tlmgr` (TeX live) or 'MikTeX Update' (MikTeX - in admin and user mode).

Comment: It could indeed be an update problem, like moewe says. The acro package has been updated on a frequent basis in the last few months (which is a good thing, as it's actively being developed).

Comment: Thank you @moewe, after some updating it now works. Unfortunately i don't know which package actually caused the problem because the acro-package was up to date but the MikTex updater found a lot of packages that needed updating... :)

Comment: I suspect it was some LaTeX3 related package such as `expl3` or `xparse`, but we can't be sure now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was solved by updating the packages involved.

Comment: I have voted to close your question as 'off-topic'. It is not off topic at all, but that is the reason we normally use when closing questions that were just caused by outdated packages and version mismatches.

Comment: @moewe okey that seems fair :) once again: thank you!